# How to delete Directories in blob storage from Logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Despite my lack of experience with Azure, I am aware that I can delete blobs from Logic app. Is it possible to delete directories from the logic app?

When I try to remove a directory, I receive the following error.

```
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "Specified resource /success/dir1 not found.\r\nclientRequestId: f97c5ba9-feb1-4b03-a9d8-d42bbc10f639",
  "error": {
    "message": "Specified resource /success/dir1 not found."
  },
  "source": "azureblob-cus.azconn-cus-001.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the workarounds is to delete all blobs present in that particular folder. To achieve this you can use the `Delete blob` action along with `List blobs`. Below is the flow that worked for me.

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you the solution is working fine but I'm still unsure if there's a way to delete directly using logicapps?

Comment: @Shubam afaik there is no direct action for this.